# How to store variably-sized relationships in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, sqlalchemy

First things first, I come to you as someone who is relatively unexperienced with databases so for any mistakes I made I do apologise.

In my current database, 2 sorts of things are stored: people (and information about those people), and the newspapers they like. My main table looks something like this:

[image]

This works well enough, however now as my application grows, I am now starting to find people who like more than 1 newspaper! My (presumably ignorant) solution was to create the new column - called multiple_favourite - This would either have a 'yes' or a 'no' in it.

If it contained a 'no', this meant that the person only had 1 favourite newspaper, and it was listed right next to it in the 'favourite_newspaper' column. However it is had a 'yes' in it, then it meant the person like more than 1 newspaper.

My application would then navigate to another table, which looked something like this:

[image]

Now, whenever my application came across someone who had a 'yes' in the 'multiple_favourite' row, it would navigate to this table, find the relevant user ID, and extract the list. This is a good solution insofar as it works, but it feels like pretty bad practice to have to unzip a list everytime you want to find a bit of data.

Furthermore, it makes filtering results of the 'multiple_newspapers' table nearly impossible. For example, say you wanted to find out the names of every single person who liked both 'the onion' and 'the daily mail'. the only way to do it in this setup is to iterate through every row of the table, unpack the list, and check if those 2 items exist.

This works fine for small databases, however when it comes to scalability surely this is bound to fail.

My question therefore is, how do I get around this problem? It feels like there must be an obvious solution which I'm glancing over but for the life of me I can't seem to find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalise it, have a table for newspapers and have a many to many relationship between the two.

Comment: Thanks @Gumerhara. Why would it be many-to-many and not just a single-to-many? The single being the person entry in the first database and the many being the multiple rows in the other table

Comment: Person A likes papers P and Q.  Newspaper P is liked by persons A and B.  That's many-many.  And it takes an extra table.